# How do I copy a file/directory from host into a LXD container?

Tags: lxd, container

I have a file/directory on the host that I want to copy into the LXD container.

What is the command to copy the host -> container?

Comment: From the host cp source destination.  What problem are you having with that, we need more information

Answer (score 13):

Suppose we want to copy `file.txt` from host to `/home/ubuntu/` directory of the `container1`

`lxc file push file.txt container1/home/ubuntu/`

to copy a directory from host to container, use `-r`

`lxc file push -r direcoty/ vm1/home/ubuntu/`

to copy file from container to host, use `pull`

`lxc file pull vm1/home/ubuntu/file.txt .`